# Icon backdrop on Samsung Galaxy S? how to change this?

Tags: android, icons, launcher

I see a backdrop being added to my launch icon on the Samsung Galaxy S devices. I need this backdrop changed to a custom backdrop which we created. I know this can be changed since apps like"Daily Briefing" have their own cloud like backdrop making the launch icon look really rich. If anyone does know how to change this backdrop please let me know.

> Take a look at the Icon for **DAILY
>   BRIEFING**. You can notice the cloud backdrop for DAILY BRIEFING. 
>   I would like to control the
>   Icon backdrop and if possible the size
>   of the Icon Eg. See difference between
>   the size of **GOOD** and **YAHOOMAIL**

[image]

Thanks in advance.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: I do not know what a "backdrop" is, but I strongly encourage you to stick to the launcher icon design guidelines: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html

Comment: i have attached a screen-shot to make things more clear. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

The backdrop is Samsung specific. If there is a way to remove it, I would check on Samsung's developer site or ask them. From the apps I've worked on, I have not seen a way to change it.

Comment: True. I don't think there is a way to remove it but change should be possible.