# Android application launcher icon has a black background

Tags: android

I saved an image in photoshop using save for web, 24 bit png, with transparency checked.

I then generated my icons using the Android Asset Studio.

My launcher icon has a black background on my device (Captivate), but does look fine on my emulator.

Any advice  on how to get the icon to not have the black background on my device?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samsung TouchWiz is what's putting the icon backdrops on.

Answer (score 1):

Save it as a 32 bit png, that way you get the full 8-bit transparency.

Comment: Thanks Geobits.  I dug around a bit more and realized it's not anything I'm doing wrong, but something that Galaxy S devices seem to be doing - inserting icon backdrops.  Below is a related question on this, however no one has specified a clear way to change it.  I'm fine with letting Galaxy S devices set it if there's not an easy way to change it.  [Samsung Galaxy S features icon backdrops in Launcher, any way to specify it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997124/samsung-galaxy-s-features-icon-backdrops-in-launcher-any-way-to-specify-it)

Comment: Here's another related question: [Icon backdrop on Samsung Galaxy S? how to change this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599743/icon-backdrop-on-samsung-galaxy-s-how-to-change-this)

Comment: Ah, I never even thought of this.... then again, the first thing I did with mine was get rid of TouchWiz in favor of ADW